# asp.net mvc3, need help to get this route constraint working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

it works as long as the topic is all lowercase, is there a way to ignore case?

```
        routes.MapRouteLowercase(
            "TopicList", // Route name
            "{topic}s/{page}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Review", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, Topic = "AllTopic" },
            new { topic = @"(app|book|toy|website|article||alltopic)" }
        );
```

Comment: What is that "routes.MapRouteLowercase"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
new { topic = @"(?i)(app|book|toy|website|article||alltopic)" }
```

Comment: thank you so much, searched on google for hrs coudlnt find the answer.